# how to put parameter value in prefix search of SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am performing SQL prefix search in my ASP.NET application.For this purpose I have written a stored procedure in which i am writing following query:

```
SELECT Description, ProductDescriptionID
FROM Production.ProductDescription
WHERE CONTAINS (Description, ' "top*" ' );
```

I have parameter as `@pvchProductName` in my procedure.How can i replace **top** word with parameter value in above query?I am facing syntax problems with single and double quotations.

Comment: @agent007: I have already posted problem relevant code.

Comment: Wajid. Whats the purpose of c# here? I think its pure sql problem. You should mention sql server as well. And Parameter name or parameter value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @searchTerm nvarchar(60) = N' "' + @pvchProductName + N'*" ';
// where the "60" above should be adjusted to account for the length
// of pvchProductName, plus 5. So if pvchProductName is [n]varchar(30),
// then nvarchar(35) would be fine.

SELECT Description, ProductDescriptionID
FROM Production.ProductDescription
WHERE CONTAINS (Description, @searchTerm);
```

?

It is unclear, however, how much of the quotes / asterisks / whitespace you want to include in the filter condition - you may want to check that a bit.

Comment: I have tried this but it shows error as : Incorrect syntax near '+'. Also this is some thing like this : "@pvchProductName*".But I need like this: ' "@pvchProductName *" '

Comment: I want that : ' "@pvchProductName *" ' according to MSDN sample example.My requirement is to simply replace actual word by parameter name.But i am facing syntax error on every edit.

Comment: @WajidAli do you really mean "parameter name"? or do you mean "the value of the parameter" ? The code I've posted should do exactly what you need. If it isn't please demonstrate with a few sample `Description` values and a `@pvchProductName` that doesn't work as expected. Also, note that `CONTAINS` is not a `LIKE` search: if `@pvchProductName` was `abc`, your `Description` would need to include (at any location) the text `' "abc*" '`, including the space at the start and end and the asterisk (but not the single-quotes). Because that is what your original "top" example did.

Comment: I want value of that parameter on that place means not want to hard code any word.

Comment: @WajidAli and indeed, the code I've shown does not hard code any word; if does what you asked in the question: where **top** appears in the question, the value of `@pvchProductName` is used. If `@pvchProductName` has the value `top`, then the queries are identical.

Comment: My brother I have told you that your solution shows : Incorrect syntax near '+'.please do not mind it but is it my fault?

Comment: Simply, @pvchProductName is parameter and i want this parameter in place of : top

Comment: @WajidAli two secs while I check SSMS

Comment: Now SQL shows me :The argument type "nvarchar(max)" is invalid for argument 2 of "CONTAINS"

Comment: @WajidAli then make it smaller ;p If `@pvchProductName` is length-20, then `nvarchar(25)` would be fine, etc